# How do I get the union type of all key-value pairs in an object in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an object like this:

```
const person = {
  id: 87
  name: 'Some Name',
  address: {
    street: 'Some street',
    country: 'Some country'
  }
}
```

I want to get a type that is the union of all key value pairs. So the type should be:

```
{ id: number } | { name: string } | { address: { street: string; country: string; } }
```

How can that be done? I tried this:

```
type PersonInfo = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  address: {
    street: string;
    country: string;
  }
}

type PersonMap<M extends { [index: string]: any }> = {
  [Key in keyof M]: M[Key]
};

type PersonTest1 = PersonMap<PersonInfo>[keyof PersonMap<PersonInfo>];
// Returns "number | string | { street: string; country: string; }"

type PersonTest2 = PersonMap<PersonInfo>;
// Returns { id: number; name: string; address: { street: string; country: string;} }
```

How can I get the union type described above?

Comment: why don't you just define the types separately then combine them to make your personinfo?

Comment: @DanielA.White I could do that, I was just wondering if there was some shortcut. The example above is just an example - in reality I have a really big object with lots of key-value pairs in it and I'd like to easily get the union type all those pairs.

Comment: It's possible with array entries. It does not seem to be possible with single k/v objects, from what I can tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you want a type function of the form `UnionOfSingleKeyObjects<T>` which turns an object type `T` into a union of single-key object types where each key in `keyof T` appears exactly once.  Depending on your use cases, you could define such a type function like this:

```
type UnionOfSingleKeyObjects<T extends object> = 
  { [K in keyof T]-?: { [P in K]: T[P] } }[keyof T]
```

And verify that it works for `PersonInfo` as desired:

```
type PersonKVPairs = UnionOfSingleKeyObjects<PersonInfo>
/* type PersonKVPairs = {
    id: number;
} | {
    name: string;
} | {
    address: {
        street: string;
        country: string;
    };
} */
```

---

The definition of `UnionOfSingleKeyObjects` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where we iterate over each key type `K` in `keyof T`, calculate the single-key object in question for each key, and then [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with `keyof T` to get a union of all single-key object types.

Instead of indexing into a mapped type, you could use [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to get the same effect:

```
type UnionOfSingleKeyObjects<T extends object> =
    keyof T extends infer K ? K extends keyof T ?
    { [P in K]: T[P] } : never : never
```

Either way works; I tend to use mapped types because they are a bit easier to explain than conditional type distributivity.

---

In both of those approaches, the single-key object with key `K` is written as `{[P in K]: T[P] }`.  This can alternatively be written as `Record<K, T[K]>` using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype), or as `Pick<T, K>` using [the `Pick<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys).  These other versions have their pros and cons, and may change how the type appears in IntelliSense quickinfo as well as whether or not optional/`readonly` keys stay optional/`readonly` in the output.  If you care about preserving these modifiers and don't want to see `Pick` or `Record` in your quickinfo, you can write it like `{[P in keyof Pick<T, K>]: T[P]}`, like this:

```
type UnionOfSingleKeyObjects<T extends object> =
    { [K in keyof T]-?: { [P in keyof Pick<T, K>]: T[P] } }[keyof T]
```

and we can see that such modifiers are preserved:

```
type Example = UnionOfSingleKeyObjects<{ a?: string, readonly b: number }>
/* type Example = {
    a?: string;
} | {
    readonly b: number;
} */
```

Again, depending on your use cases, you may or may not care about such things.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOwJKoGbKgXigG8AoKMqASwBMAuKVAVwFsAjBAblPNQEMmI6iYPAqoA5p3JQeVKvAiJEdElKlD5EYIOGiJXVVADGyBqmEhtI8ZPIBfYveJOA9M6ihIUAKqoKaAPJYAMq6ADYQANIQIP4sAFYQhsCIADwAKlAQAB7AEKhUiFDI8YnAAHz4RFAA2hGUqFAA1tHIWFBpALoAtAD8yjUw9VARHXRp1TAdULbT1c0gre0dTh7QPn6ogSHi4VExJUmpGdm5+YXFCUkVePpVtUPzi529-RMPLW0wFIaN6QA0wzKo3aEymM1scw+SxW4GgcCQaAiADUYDwKEhKusAsEwpForFLskUvCUBhsMgysRnAAqdyw2AIUnI1HowoEFTkah0RisDgOKAAHyIt14-Esuk4MyFHLIMjkCiUwoMZHUEE04ustykxlM5g1eiktklUGpzhhngAolk+GBwpjfNjtmJdviDkTCNI+lB1LoAfIZGhQiAoCxucw2PBppSaXTLdamLboOzbjwvT7NVKleR-VRA8HQ-Rw3yZqanKKFGAeIZoAARCg+lgAYTQVAowA2PFCwtuq28Ds2OJ2eP2hKOmRyeQKRTd1y15EebWOE7O9SwCGGUB6G5Ok8KC-am7nZA9b1Ew2B40m0yg3IgADd17eH-AnFJeyTESi0RiCFiB06XRHUpUg-MkcEpKQY3fRlPxZH8swMLlC15eAbDITMZVUct9TQ69pSPaRZHkRRlAItRhDVLRvR0TVlVUHUzHgCxqKsA1lSNW4SzNBwgA)

Comment: Why is the [P in K] required in type UnionOfSingleKeyObjects<T extends object> = { [K in keyof T]-?: { [P in K]: T[P] } }[keyof T] ?

I.e. since K is here just a single key - why can't we just do { [K]: T[K] }? I know it throws an error but I don't understand why since P and K seem to be the same thing.

Comment: Well, as you said, it throws an error; computed property syntax `{[k]: YYY}` only works if `k` is a *value*, not a *type*, (and additionally the type of `k` must be a literal or unique symbol).  We're using mapped types, not computed properties. The syntax for mapped types is `{[P in XXX]: YYY}` where `XXX` is a key type or union of key types and `YYY` is a type that possibly depends on `P`.  Even if you have just one key, you have to write `[P in K]` for it to work.